# How does sorting come into play with convex hull?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I am investigating a convex hull algorithm that involves sorting. In fact, its running time is limited by sorting, so it is $O(n \log n)$, where $n$ is the number of points on the plane.

That algorithm first sorts the points by x-coordinates. It then includes the first and last points in the convex hull. From there on, I am confused. How could an algorithm like this get the other points of the hull?

Comment: Which algorithm are you looking at? There are several that involve sorting (q.v. [Convex Hull Algorithms on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms)).

Comment: He is most likely talking about the incremental algorithm for the convex hull. What I do not understand is what exactly is your misunderstanding, David?

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to catch the connection with sorting if you first sort the points by their **polar angle**. This is the basic idea for the [Graham scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan). Though, the idea with sorting points by the x-coordinates also works: you need then to apply just a slight modification of the same Graham's algorithm.